# Need to implement a phase locked frequency converter from 32768Hz to 36000Hz. How would I go about it?

Tags: frequency, clock, conversion

I am building a timecode-related application and need to generate a square-wave clock pulse of 36000 which is integer-dividable down to 24,25 and 30. My source clock is 32768Hz which does not divide down to integer values. I believe therefore I need to convert the 32768Hz clock to 36000Hz.

There's also options to convert up from 1Hz, 1024Hz, 2048Hz or 4086Hz although I suspect the approach would be similar.

How would I best go about this?

Comment: The greatest common factor of these is 32Hz so /1024,*1125 is one approach. Another is to consider replacing the crystal with a 60kHz one... http://uk.farnell.com/citizen-finetech-miyota/cfv206-60-000kazf-ub/crystal-60k-12-5pf-cl-6x2mm-cyl/dp/1611704?categoryId=700000005191&categoryName=

Comment: What hardware have you to do this? When you say 'square-wave' must it be an exactly-equal duty cycle? 24Hz, 25Hz and 30Hz can all be derived using integer division (but not limited to dividing by powers of two) from 600Hz.

Comment: Don't understand what frequncies do you want: 24Hz, 25Hz and 30Hz? Forget about source 32768Hz, this Xtal is used for 1Hz time base

Comment: ok so I am looking at a TCXO chip from Max. This outputs the 32768Hz waveform, but also has the other output options mentioned. The 24,25,30 mentioned as outputs are used for frame boundaries relating to 24fps, 25fps, 30fps.

Answer (score 1):

Specifications, specifications, specifications.

What jitter is required on your divided down signals?

If they need to be clean enough to run an RF synthesiser from, then you need a synthesiser to make the 36kHz, either integer division to 32Hz (as suggested by Mr Drummond) to lock, or fractional division to do the phase comparison at a higher frequency, which will result in a lower phase noise.

However, I'm guessing that you may be able to tolerate a 30uS tange of jitter on your divided down signals. In which case, you can stick with your 32768Hz clock source, and use an Arduino or PIC to deliver your 24Hz signal by dividing programmatically by 1365, 1365, 1366, repeatedly. It's very straightforward to come up with similar sequences of numbers for other low frequencies.

When you know what you want to make, the options available to make it will become clearer.

Comment: I'm trying to make something that can generate rock-steady timecode. This is not an RF application. Timecode comes (generally) in a few key varieties - mainly 25fps and 24fps. USA uses 30fps and 24fps, but slowed down by 0.1%. Timecode's a tricky critter...

Comment: @Mark so how does that application translate into a specification for what level of jitter is allowed on the edges?

Comment: ok I can see  why you are asking about jitter now. I'd rather not have to worry about it at this stage and be able to divide down by equal integers, which is why I am trying to find a way of converting the original clock speed.

Comment: @Mark what is special about 32768Hz? You would have to lock it to something else anyway, 1pps from GPS, or 198kHz from radio 4 carrier, or Rugby 60kHz. If free running, you might as well have 36kHz or 60kHz free running as 32768? Why not lock a nice freqeucny to your standard, or have a nice freqeuncy free running?

Comment: 32768Hz is the oscillator output from the TCXO I was considering using for this project.

Comment: @Mark so what's making you consider a difficult to use part, when you could be considering an easier to use part?

Comment: Could you please suggest such a part?

Comment: @Mark I could easily suggest parts that don't meet your budget, size, availability, power supply, so I'm not getting into that game. However, if you tell me the part number and supplier of the 32768Hz TCXO you have in mind as your first choice, I'll look for something similar in a better frequency

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need the 36000 Hz signal somewhere, or is it simply because you want to downsample to 24,25 and 30 ?

You can tuen the 32768 clock into those rates directly. Usually you would use the interrupt from a compare timer to add a known amount to a variable, then when reaching a threshold, you substract the threshold from that sum and trigger one pulse. This way you will not get drift (but you will have a slight jitter).

Here is an example for a 10MHz clock, to get 29.97 Hz, adjust for your values.
Set the timer compare to 1000 (so the timer ISR will be called every 1000 clock). In the timer ISR, add 2997 to an integer counter. When this integer is above or equal to 1000000, substract 1000000 from it, and toggle the output pin value.

The interrupt will be called every 1000/10000000s, you will add 2997, so you will reach each cycle of 1/29.97s when the accumulation integer gets to 1000000.

The fact that you substract 1000000 instead of setting the accumulation counter to zero is what prevents any drift.

In this specific case, it is assumed the precise TCXO is acting as the clock. A similar process would work if the TCXO is triggering an interrupt on an input pin.

Comment: Did you notice the question has sat for five years?  It's unlikely the problem is still real

Comment: Is there a rule against adding detail to older questions that might be relevant to other people?

Comment: No, it's just not particularly _useful_.  And as the question was never quite complete (other people had asked five years ago for some of the clarification you are also asking for), at this point it should probably be closed.